# Make a bezier curve into a subdivided mesh?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I have created a shape using a bezier curve.  I want to give it depth and then apply an image as a displacement modifier.

I have added a face to the shape and extruded the shape into 3 dimensions. However I cannot get the face to subdivide so I cannot apply the displacement modifier.

How can I get a detailed enough mesh across that face?

[image: Here is an image of my mesh]

The face I want to add detail to is selected.

[image: I want to add a displacement map so it becomes like this without the surrounding plane. But I need more detail in the top plane to get the image to work.]

Comment: Hello, could you provide some pictures so that we could understand your need more precisely ?

Comment: Hi lemon, thanks for commenting.  I have added an image of my mesh now and another of something similar to what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Use a boolean. Make a face on top/bottom parts of the curve shape. Make a grid with the displacement image. Apply the displacement. Then intersect the displaced grid with with your ex curve.

Comment: Hi lemon, what do you mean by make a grid with the displacement image?

Comment: Hi PaddyGould, simply the same as you probably did in your second screen capture. If you intersect (boolean modifier) it with the curve above (converted to mesh and bottom & top faces closed) you will obtain what you want, if I have well understood

Comment: Do you need me to add an answer for that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For subdivide you need **quads**. Upper face is unsightly **ngon** and **can't be subdivided**. *Remesh* modifier should be helpful in this case.

If *Remesh* doesn't  do its job well, you can delete ngon and fill area manually with smaller parts by selecting two opposite verts and pres <kbd>F</kbd> to fill and press <kbd>J</kbd> to connect.

You can combine this procedure with *Grid Fill* - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> > <kbd>G</kbd>

I don't know a better solution, I hope someone knows one because this is really good question.

Comment: The Remesh option worked for me.  Thanks Shubol3D, I appreciate your help and time !